# How to use TextInputLayout in new android design library

Tags: android, android-design-library

Recently google introduced new Android Design Library in that how to use `TextInputLayout` field to enable the Floating Hint feature of EditText.

Not much guidance is available [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

This page says

> you can now wrap it in a TextInputLayout

But No idea because smart prediction (Ctrl+SPACE) doesn't predicts any attributes to the TextInputLayout. So my questions are:

How do we get hold of the EditText underlying this component?

How can we get data from EditText?

Comment: The question is clear and useful...

Comment: This question is clear and quite useful since there is not much guide available for the Design Library's implementations!

Comment: Check **[this tutorial](http://chintanrathod.com/textinputlayout-material-design-support-library-tutorial/)**, its helpful.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`TextInputLayout` extends `ViewGroup` class.
So which means that you have to wrap your `EditText` in a `TextInputLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: @moictab It's in the design support library, so it's available for API 7+.

Comment: Well, I've tried it in API 19 and I got an exception when inflating the view. Maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I've tried your solution and run it on my lolipop device, but the TextInputLaayout doesnt work

Comment: @moictab Make sure you add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` to your gradle dependencies.

Comment: TextInputLayout is really nice. I just followed this guide here>> http://charmndroid.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-use-textinputlayout-in-android.html. It says you have to initialize the TextInputLayout and not the EditText and then take the controls!

Comment: Why is the height of TextInputLayout `wrap_content`?

Comment: why does the official doc example use a textInputEditText instead of edit text https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Comment: Does anyone know the difference between a standard `EditText` and `TextInputLayout`?

Answer (score 6):

Do wrap the `TextInputLayout` around `TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`.

Wrapping around `EditText` does have issue in landscape mode. Refer to 
[this article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/all-internet-tutorials-on-textinputlayout-miss-this-5dfab878a048#.enwq483pi) for more details.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is defined in [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) under "Floating labels for editing text".

```
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_et_textinputlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/FeedBackerNameET"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="hinttext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords" />
     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this works well, you should let you app theme extends from `Theme.AppCompat` (or its descendant) theme, like extends from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/type_message"
        android:maxLines="5"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

hint will automatically shift up once you start typing in the edit text and to have those errors which appear below edit text set error on text input layout like this not on edit text

```
tilMessage.setError("Message field is empty!");
```

to disable error

```
tilMessage.setErrorEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way...

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/card_id_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/form_card_id_text"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**If you use EditText like a child of TextInputLayout, you will see this message in Android Monitor:**

> I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) there is a new [**`TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) component.

Just use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image][image]

In the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) you can find all the info.

Answer (score 0):

We can use AppCompactEditText also for this need to add support:appcompat in gradle

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule of Thumb : TextInputLayout should wrap TextInputEditText instead of the normal EditText.

Reason?
TextInputEditText is a sub-class of EditText and is designed for use as a child of TextInputLayout.

Furthermore, using an EditText instead would shoot us a warning : EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.